# Overactive SQL Injection Attack Firewall Rules

Tags: firewall, sql, sophos

We have a web app that our client's employees use to submit signatures from customers using HTML5 canvas to create PNG images.  The signature pad is converted to base64 encoded HTTP POST data.  Our legitimate traffic is flagged as SQL Injection by their router/firewall because it violates the rule defined to prevent SQL injection, specifically due to the XOR operator.  We don't want to turn off the firewall rule, especially since it seems to be only the XOR operator, but need to find a way to allow this traffic.  Is there any way to modify this rule to accomodate or is the only solution turning it off?  Otherwise is there a way to make the rule apply site-wide but turn it off for just the one script it's needed on?

Firewall: Sophos- I'm not sure of the model, firmware, etc. but our customer is still able to get updates which come with new firewall rules switched on by default.  This is the 3rd time in a year and a half that the image POST data has been blocked by the firewall.

Web Server: Apache/PHP, not that this should matter much as the web app works fine when not blocked by a firewall.

Actual line of firewall's log:

```
[msg "SQL Injection Attack: SQL Operator Detected"] [data "Matched Data: XOr found within ARGS:tmp_img: data:image/png;base64,....
```

Comment: The "XOR operator"? Do you mean the caret? If not, then what are you referring to?

Comment: I'm thinking it's the actual string "xor" because it appears in the log as mixed cases, but unfortunately it truncates the data for the log so I can't see the whole string.
[data "Matched Data: XOr found within ARGS:tmp_img: data:image/png;base64,....
I do see a partial representation of the base64 data, but not even close to all of it.  Notice the case in "XOr", then later "xor", "xOR", and "xOr".

Comment: Your customer needs to yell at Sophos more loudly this time.

Comment: Sorry, edited comment due to I forgot I needed shift+enter, but yes I think that might be appropriate lol.  I'm not sure if they have support, but as the dev for the web app I of course get the complaint first.  We should also look into reducing the quality of our customer service to pass the buck onto other companies more :)

Comment: Most people don't call the roads department - or worse, their plumber! - when their car won't start. This really isn't your problem.

Comment: Right, thanks!  I just contacted our customer and said to either whitelist the page that accepts the image POST (only 1 script) or allow the XOR operator in the rules while still disallowing other SQL attacks.  I hope he knows how to do it cuz I don't lol.